# Функция для работы с числами

Tags: php

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, функцию, которая превращает обычные цифры в удобочитаемые.

Пример: **1000000** - **1 000 000**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужна функция [number_format](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php)

$new_number = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');